# Return IQueryable<T> from another class instance

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

What I'm trying to accomplish is to make a base class that returns a general purpose `IQueryable<T>` and use that `IQueryable` from another class instance to filter further. 
Es.
The base class return all records, and the calling class filters from there on.

This is the base class and getDealer_query is the method that returns the main `IQueryable`

```
 public class Dealer
 {
    public DAL.DBConn_Nav db = null;
    public G4.Elements.Identity oIdentity = null;

    public Dealer()
    {
        oIdentity = new G4.Elements.Identity();
        oIdentity.read();
    }

    public IQueryable<outerViewModel.NavisionDAL.vmDealer> getDealer_query()
    {
        IQueryable<vmDealer> dealer = (from d in db.DENTALICA_S_P_A__Customer
                                       select new vmDealer()
                                       {
                                           idDealer = d.No_,
                                           name = d.Name + (d.Name_2.Length > 0 ? " " + d.Name_2 : ""),
                                           address = d.Address + (d.Address_2.Length > 0 ? " " + d.Address_2 : ""),
                                           city = d.City,
                                           zip = d.Post_Code,
                                           county = d.County,
                                           email = d.E_Mail,
                                           phone = d.Phone_No_,
                                           fax = d.Fax_No_,
                                           vat = d.VAT_Registration_No_,
                                           ssn = d.Fiscal_Code,
                                           businessAreaCode = d.Business_Area_Code,
                                           businessZoneCode = d.Business_Zone_Code,
                                           clienteDiretto = (d.Cliente_Diretto == (byte)1 ? true : false),
                                           aggancioOrdiniWeb = (d.Deposito_Agg__Ordini_Web == (byte)1 ? true : false),
                                           aggancioOrdiniG4 = (d.Deposito_Agg__Ordini_G4 == (byte)1 ? true : false),
                                           notUse = (d.Not_Use == (byte)1 ? true : false),
                                           blocked = d.Blocked,
                                           shipmentMethodCode = d.Shipment_Method_Code,
                                           paymentTermsCode = d.Payment_Terms_Code,
                                           paymentMethodCode = d.Payment_Method_Code,
                                           shippingAgentCode = d.Shipping_Agent_Code,
                                           customerPriceGroup = d.Customer_Price_Group,
                                           customerDiscountGroup = d.Customer_Disc__Group,
                                           identificaCliente = d.Identifica_Cliente

                                       });
        return dealer;
    }
```

Here is the other Class `Customer` that calls the method from an instance of `Dealer` and finally Lists data.

```
public class Customer
{
    G4.Elements.Identity oIdentity = null;
    DAL.DBConn_Nav navDB = null;

    public Customer()
    {
        //oIdentity = new G4.Elements.Identity();
        //oIdentity.read();
    }

    ///// <summary>
    ///// Recupera l'elenco dei clienti Navision (i Depositi pr G4) visibili ad un particolare utente
    ///// </summary>
    ///// <returns></returns>
    public IQueryable<outerViewModel.NavisionDAL.vmDealer> getCustomerForOperator_query()
    {
        string idOperator = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(oIdentity.selectedId) ? oIdentity.selectedId : oIdentity.id;

        using (navDB = new DAL.DBConn_Nav()) {
            G4.Models.NavisionDAL.Dealer oD = new G4.Models.NavisionDAL.Dealer();
            // Tutti i Clienti
            IQueryable<outerViewModel.NavisionDAL.vmDealer> allCustomerList_query = oD.getDealer_query();
            IQueryable<outerViewModel.NavisionDAL.vmDealer> customerForOperator_query = (from c in allCustomerList_query                                                                                join cForOp in navDB.DENTALICA_S_P_A__SalesPerson_Customer on c.idDealer equals cForOp.Customer_No_
                                                                                         where cForOp.Salesperson_Code.Equals(idOperator)
                                                                                         && cForOp.Starting_Date < DateTime.Now
                                                                                         && (cForOp.Ending_Date.Equals(new DateTime(1753, 1, 1)) || cForOp.Ending_Date > DateTime.Now)
                                                                                         && c.notUse.Equals(false)
                                                                                      select c).Distinct();

            return customerForOperator_query;
        }
    }

    public List<G4.outerViewModel.NavisionDAL.vmDealer> getCustomerForOperator()
    {
        using (navDB = new DAL.DBConn_Nav())
        {
            G4.Models.NavisionDAL.Dealer oD = new G4.Models.NavisionDAL.Dealer();
            return getCustomerForOperator_query().ToList();
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work! I get a generic "Object not set to an instance...".

Even if I try to debug I get nowhere cause the cursor doesn't stop.

To make it work I have to inherit the Dealer class from the Customer, but it is not what I want.

I think I'm missing something basic here.

Any Idea ?

**EDIT - Simplified sample**
I'm adding a simplified sample of the same code.

```
public class Dealer1
{

    public DAL.DBConn_Nav db = null;

    public Dealer1() { 

    }

    public IQueryable<outerViewModel.NavisionDAL.vmDealer> getDealer_query()
    {

        IQueryable<vmDealer> dealer = (from d in db.DENTALICA_S_P_A__Customer

                                       select new vmDealer()
                                       {
                                           idDealer = d.No_,
                                           name = d.Name + (d.Name_2.Length > 0 ? " " + d.Name_2 : "")

                                       });

        return dealer;

    }
}


 public class Customer1
{

    public DAL.DBConn_Nav db = null;

    public Customer1()
    {

    }

    public IQueryable<outerViewModel.NavisionDAL.vmDealer> getCustomerForOperator_query()
    {

        // All customers
        G4.Models.NavisionDAL.Dealer1 oD = new G4.Models.NavisionDAL.Dealer1();

        IQueryable<outerViewModel.NavisionDAL.vmDealer> allCustomerList_query = oD.getDealer_query().Where(i => i.name.StartsWith("AAA"));

        return allCustomerList_query;

    }

    public List<G4.outerViewModel.NavisionDAL.vmDealer> getCustomerForOperator()
    {

        using (db = new DAL.DBConn_Nav())
        {
            return getCustomerForOperator_query().ToList();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in your class `Dealer` that is setting the instance of `db`.

```
public DAL.DBConn_Nav db = null;
```

So even though in `Customer` you call `using (navDB = new DAL.DBConn_Nav())` you are not passing `navDB` to `Dealer` so when you call `getDealer_query()` you get a null reference exception.

---

Based on your simplified sample I would recommend this code:

```
public class Dealer1
{
    internal IQueryable<vmDealer> getDealer_query(DAL.DBConn_Nav db)
    {
        return
            from d in db.DENTALICA_S_P_A__Customer
            select new vmDealer()
            {
                idDealer = d.No_,
                name = String.Join(" ", d.Name, d.Name_2)
            };
    }
}

public class Customer1
{
    internal IQueryable<vmDealer> getCustomerForOperator_query(DAL.DBConn_Nav db)
    {
        return new Dealer1().getDealer_query(db).Where(i => i.name.StartsWith("AAA"));
    }

    public List<vmDealer> getCustomerForOperator()
    {
        using (var db = new DAL.DBConn_Nav())
        {
            return getCustomerForOperator_query(db).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

This cleanly allows you to segregate responsibility, but it keeps you totally in control of the `db` instance - which you need to dispose of when done.

Comment: I think you've spotted the problem, but I don't know how to turn it into working coed. I've added a simplified sample of the same code into 2 new classes Dealer1 and Customer1.
How should I handle the DAL.DBConn_Nav db to make it work ?

Comment: Excellent ! It works great and it is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a reason why `allCustomerList_query` is null.

To confirm that the linq statement in the `getDealer_query` method is working, I would change your code to look this:

```
        List<outerViewModel.NavisionDAL.vmDealer> something = new List<outerViewModel.NavisionDAL.vmDealer>();
        IQueryable<outerViewModel.NavisionDAL.vmDealer> test = something.AsQueryable();
        return test;
```

In any case, to prevent the object ref error, you need to guarantee that an instance is returned, which, from the code example, I can't actually tell.

It's rather strange that you can't get a break point to stop inside the `getDealer_query` method. Are you running this in a test with multiple threads running? What could happen is that the other thread is having an unhandled exception raised, and thus the whole test stops. Try putting break points before `return dealer` in `getDealer_query` and on the line `G4.Models.NavisionDAL.Dealer oD = new G4.Models.NavisionDAL.Dealer();`. Assuming there are no other threads, the code has to stop on one of those.

Last note, looking at the code, I don't see where `db` is instantiated. If it isn't instantiated, you'll get an object ref error on this line:

```
    `IQueryable<vmDealer> dealer = (from d in db.DENTALICA_S_P_A__Customer`
```